# fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address (docker contaIner)

Tags: git, docker, ssh, containers, pull

I'm currently trying to manage multiple git repositories stored in a docker container. My goal is to update these repositories every time I run the container. To do that, I run a Python script located inside the container which iterates over all the repositories folders executing the `git pull` command.

The problem is that when the script is executed I get the following output:

[image]

When I searched for possible solutions to the problem, I found that the only solution would be to set SSH keys inside the container. For me, that method is not user-friendly, specially because I need other people to execute the tool inside the container and not all of them uses the SSH keys method.

So my question is: Is there any way to execute the `git pull` command without using the SSH keys?

I have the following Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile to run Git Truck https://github.com/git-truck/git-truck
FROM node:latest
LABEL MANTAINER="jcarrascoa7"

# Set the working directory in the image
WORKDIR /app

# Copy all files from the directory where the Dockerfile is located to /app (this Dockerfile must be in the same 
# directory as the GitHub repositories that will be analyzed)
COPY . .

# Install dependencies

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install xdg-utils --fix-missing
RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN npm install git-truck

# Update repositories and run Git Truck

CMD python3 downloader.py;npx git-truck@latest
```

And the `downloader.py`:

```
import os

__author__ = "Jose Antonio Castro"
__github__ = "Baelfire18"

main = os.getcwd()

groups = [f"group1", f"group2", f"group3", f"group4"]
repositories = ["repo1", "repo2", "repo3"]

for group in groups:
    for repo in repositories:
        name = f"{group}-{repo}"
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(name):
                print(f"Git cloning {name}")
                os.system(f"git clone https://github.com/iic2154-uc-cl/{name}.git")
            else:
                print(f"Git pulling {name}")
                os.chdir(name)
                os.system("git stash")
                os.system("git pull --ff-only")
        except Exception as error:
            print(f'Error con {name}.\n{error}\nprint("F")')
        finally:
            os.chdir(main)
            print("\n")
```

Comment: The docker container has no `/dev/tty`; your https repository requires a user name and/or password and the credential manager you selected decided to read the user name and/or password from `/dev/tty`, which failed. Choose a different credential manager, provide the user name and/or password, provide a `/dev/tty` that connects to the user to supply the name and/or password, and/or do the clone outside the docker instance.